# What does "Gau" in GauGAN stand for?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, generative-adversarial-networks, image-generation

GauGAN is a neural network architecture from NVIDIA that can create realistic images from semantic maps (and nowadays also textual descriptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, GauGAN is the following (from [this post](https://www.iotworldtoday.com/2021/11/25/nvidia-launches-latest-gaugan-ai-landscape-generation-model/)):

> GauGAN was a Microsoft Paint-style platform that let uses create landscape images, with the model then able to turn them into photorealistic images.

So, it is a generative adversarial network (GAN) to create images. As it works like an artist, its authors named it GauGAN after "Paul **Gau**guin" who was a French Post-Impressionist artist (refer into [this post](https://ddg.wiki/gaugan/)).